# How to convert ByteArray to String with specified charset in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I found there is a [ByteArray.toString(charset:Charset)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-string.html) function in Kotlin,when I use that function in android studio IDE,it gets a syntax error. But I have tried the same code in Kotlin org site, it works well. How can I convert a ByteArray to String in Kotlin?

[image: Android Studio error Message]

Comment: i am not getting that error using your code only.

Comment: Try this constructor: `String(bytes, charset)`. Also check if Kotlin stdlib included in your project.

Comment: You can try with val str = String(bytes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you didn't configure your project for Kotlin (there is no kotlin-runtime.jar in your classpath). Try to select the line with the error, press `Alt+Enter` and in context menu choose "Kotlin not configured" -> "Configure"
Or manually add kotlin-runtime.jar to your classpath

[image]